# spring boot on azure Internal Server Error

Tags: docker, spring-boot, kubernetes, kubectl

I have a very simple "Hello" spring-boot application

```
@RestController
public class HelloWorld {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello Spring Boot!!";
    }
}
```

I packaged Dockerfile

```
FROM java:8
COPY ./springsimple-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /Users/a/Documents/dev/intellij/dockerImages/
WORKDIR /Users/a/Documents/dev/intellij/dockerImages/  
EXPOSE 8090
CMD ["java", "-jar", "springsimple-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

and pulled into my container registry and deployed it

```
amhg$ kubectl run testproject --image acontainerregistry.azurecr.io/hellospring:v1 
    deployment.apps "testproject" created
amhg$ kubectl expose deployments testproject --port=5000 --type=LoadBalancer
    service "testproject" exposed
```

command kubectl get pods

```
NAME                               READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
    testproject-bdf5b54d-gkk92         1/1       Running            0          41s
```

However when I try the command  (Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001) I got the error:

```
 amhg$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/default/pods/testproject-bdf5b54d-gkk92/
    Internal Server Error
```

What is missing?

The description of the pod is

```
amhg$ kubectl describe pod testproject-bdf5b54d-gkk92
Name:           testproject-bdf5b54d-gkk92
Namespace:      default
Node:           aks-nodepool1-39744669-0/10.240.0.4
Start Time:     Thu, 19 Apr 2018 13:13:20 +0200
Labels:         pod-template-hash=68916108
                run=testproject
Annotations:    kubernetes.io/created-by={"kind":"SerializedReference","apiVersion":"v1","reference":{"kind":"ReplicaSet","namespace":"default","name":"testproject-bdf5b54d","uid":"aa99808e-43c2-11e8-9537-0a58ac1f0f4...
Status:         Running
IP:             10.244.0.40
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/testproject-bdf5b54d
Containers:
  testproject:
    Container ID:   docker://6ed3878fa4476a5d2e56f0ba70908742702709c7505c7b19989efc6ff658ea55
    Image:          acontainerregistry.azurecr.io/hellospring:v1
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://acontainerregistry.azurecr.io/azure-vote-front@sha256:e2af252d275c99b802e21b3b469c75b256d7812ee71d7582cd759bd4faf5a6ec
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 19 Apr 2018 13:13:21 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-vkpjm (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True 
  Ready          True 
  PodScheduled   True 
Volumes:
  default-token-vkpjm:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-vkpjm
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.alpha.kubernetes.io/notReady:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.alpha.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason                 Age   From                               Message
  ----    ------                 ----  ----                               -------
  Normal  Scheduled              57m   default-scheduler                  Successfully assigned testproject-bdf5b54d-gkk92 to aks-nodepool1-39744669-0
  Normal  SuccessfulMountVolume  57m   kubelet, aks-nodepool1-39744669-0  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-vkpjm"
  Normal  Pulled                 57m   kubelet, aks-nodepool1-39744669-0  Container image "acontainerregistry.azurecr.io/hellospring:v1" already present on machine
  Normal  Created                57m   kubelet, aks-nodepool1-39744669-0  Created container
  Normal  Started                57m   kubelet, aks-nodepool1-39744669-0  Started container
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start from the beginning: it is always better to use YAML config files to do anything with Kubernetes. It will help you with debugging if something goes wrong and repeat your action in future.

First, you use the command to create the pod:

> kubectl run testproject --image acontainerregistry.azurecr.io/hellospring:v1

where YAML looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-app
spec:
  containers:
  - name: java-app
    image: acontainerregistry.azurecr.io/hellospring:v1
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8090
```

and you can apply it as a command:

```
kubectl apply -f ./pod.yaml
```

You get the same result as while running your command, but additionally you have the config file which can be used in future.

You`re trying to expose your pod using command:

> kubectl expose deployments testproject --port=5000 --type=LoadBalancer

YAML for your service looks like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: java-service
  labels:
    name: test-app
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 5000
    targetPort: 8090
    name: http
  selector:
    name: test-app
```

Doing the same but with using YAML allows to describe more and be sure you don't miss anything.

You tried to curl the localhost but I`m not sure what did you expect from this command:

> amhg$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/default/pods/testproject-bdf5b54d-gkk92/
>       Internal Server Error

After you create the service, you call `kubectl describe service $service_name`, which you can find here:

```
LoadBalancer Ingress:     XX.XX.XX.XX
Port:                     http  5000/TCP
```

You can curl this address and receive the answer from your application.

```
curl -v XX.XX.XX.XX:5000
```

Don't forget to open the port on Azure firewall.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description. I am going to test it again and let you know. From the curl  http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1... I am trying receive the value from the application  "HelloWorld". It is a simple spring boot aplication

Comment: finally I tried again, looking at the yaml files, is clear to understand, specially with identifying the name of pod and service, on my console and the Ports; the port 5000 is the one used for the External-IP, whereas 8090 the port where the container will expose the image. I tried on the browse with the External IP http://XX.XXX.XX.XX:5000/, however the browser was cycling. I tried the curl option. I got a Connection Failed message connect to XX.XXX.XX.XX port 5000 failed: Operation timed out. It has to do with the firewall ? because with previous examples it was not necessary

Comment: Yes, looks like this is firewall issue, you need to allow connection to port which you expose.